# Hibernate 5 mapping @Enumerated as bytea on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

After trying to migrate our project from Hibernate 4 to Hibernate 5, all @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) became mapped as a bytea type, resulting in "could not deserialize" error because of the wrong datatype (String -> bytea). We really need the field in String type.

Have we did something wrong or miss something in the process of the migration?

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: Hello SternK, the dialect I use are "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem with 5.4.27.Final. To what exactly hibernate version did you migrate? Please show also your hibernate config and example of problematic field with all annotations that you apply to this field.